# In Objective-c where is better to define variable from performance point of view?

Tags: objective-c, performance, variables

Where is the best place to define local variables (**which are reused**) inside the implementation:

1. Inside the code (there is option to declare it everywhere) - for example inside the loop statement.
2. At the beginning of the implementation block.
3. As global for the class variable inside the `{}` after the `@implementation myclass`.

REMARK: I suppose that this is duplicate but I am not sure which is the best. Questions that I found are about `@interface` vs `@implementation` sections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Inside the code (there is option to declare it everywhere) - for example inside the loop statement.
2. At the beginning of the implementation block.

C compilers have become extremely good at making these cases identical. You should absolutely strive for readability here, not performance. Trying to second guess the optimizer on something this trivial is going to just create a mess.

As a matter of style, most ObjC programmers tend to declare variables at the point they are first used. That tends to help you remember to delete the variable when you delete the code that uses it, and makes some kinds of by-hand refactoring much simpler. Older C programmers sometimes put all the variables at the top of the function, but that's somewhat habit from the days when this was required by C compilers. (Some still feel that putting all the variables at the top improve readability; but it's definitely not performance.)

3. As global for the class variable inside the {} after the @implementation myclass.

It depends on whether you're requiring allocation or not. As a general rule, this would make things harder on the optimizer. But if you're able to reuse an object without reallocating it, then this can be much faster. It completely depends on your program. It certainly would be horrible practice to do this regularly "because it's faster" though. In many cases it would be slower because it would get in the way of the optimizer.

These kinds of micro optimizations are generally best left to the optimizer. It can (and does) restructure your code to improve performance. Instead of focusing on this, focus on how to make sure that the piece of code you're optimizing is called less often. Changing an O(n^2) algorithm into an O(n) algorithm will completely dwarf any improvements you get by the kinds of changes you're describing.

Comment: 10x for detailed answer.